# Broadcast Receiver is not activated

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

After receiving a data from an external communication, I want to send it on broadcast in order to print it on screen.

Here is the part of my service that sends the data into broadcast:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("CodeFilter_MemoryRead"); 
intent.putExtra("data_memory_read_from_hce", MemoryStringValue);
this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

And the activity that is meant to receive it:

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final IntentFilter hceNotificationsFilter = new IntentFilter();
    hceNotificationsFilter.addAction("CodeFilter");
    registerReceiver(hceNotificationsReceiver, hceNotificationsFilter);
}    

final BroadcastReceiver hceNotificationsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String hcedata = intent.getExtras().toString();
        RealMessageReceived.setText(hcedata);
        Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast listener activated");
        }
};
```

The issue I have is that my BroadcastReceiver is never activated even after the command `this.sendBroadcast(intent)`. Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The string you create the `Intent` with doesn't match the string you add to `IntentFilter`. They need to be the same in order for the receiver to receive the intent. The following code should work:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("CodeFilter_MemoryRead"); 
intent.putExtra("data_memory_read_from_hce", MemoryStringValue);
this.sendBroadcast(intent);
```

and

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    final IntentFilter hceNotificationsFilter = new IntentFilter();
    hceNotificationsFilter.addAction("CodeFilter_MemoryRead");
    registerReceiver(hceNotificationsReceiver, hceNotificationsFilter);
}    

final BroadcastReceiver hceNotificationsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String hcedata = intent.getExtras().toString();
        RealMessageReceived.setText(hcedata);
        Log.i(TAG, "Broadcast listener activated");
        }
};
```